# How to trigger Facebook bot when user comes to your facebook page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, bots

Just wondering if it's possible to trigger the Facebook messenger bot to great a user when they land on your page?

Say I have a business page i.e. Socks by Sarah.

When a user comes to my page, can I trigger the bot to great the user with something like "Hello , this is what we offer..." or something along those lines?

Thanks

Comment: No, that is not possible. The user has to initiate the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a FB bot and am not aware of any such functionality.  The Bots are tied to Messenger which is not invoked by simply visiting a page.

Once a user sends a message to your Bot through Messenger then you can asynchronously contact them.  Many of the Bots, like the Wall Street Journal, send updates throughout the day while other will occasionally reach out.  Your general idea of keeping customers up to date about product offerings is supported and encourage but only for users that 'opt in' by sending a message.

Some links of interest:

[Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) docs are pretty good.

[Chatbot group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/chatbot/) is a FB group for developers and others interest in chatbots. There is a ton of information and links in the group.

[Facebook Robots for Fun and Profit](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c) is my article about setting up a FB Bot.

[DMS Software Bot](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions) is my example Bot.